# Dictionary overwriting previous key values on assigning new values

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

Take an example:

```
data_out = []
this_data_out = {}
this_data_out['acn'] = 123
this_data_out['name'] = 'pk'
data_out.append(this_data_out)
data_out
[{'acn': 123, 'name': 'pk'}]
this_data_out['acn'] = 124
this_data_out['name'] = 'rp'
data_out.append(this_data_out)
data_out
[{'acn': 124, 'name': 'rp'}, {'acn': 124, 'name': 'rp'}]
```

I expected the result to be

```
[{'acn': 123, 'name': 'pk'}, {'acn': 124, 'name': 'rp'}]
```

Please help me to understand how does this happen?

Thanks

Comment: If you `.append(..)` you do **not make a copy** of the dictionary: you add a reference to the dictionary in the list. So `data_out[0]` and `this_data_out` refer to the *same* dictionary. Changes made through `data_out[0]` will reflect on `this_data_out` and vice versa.

Comment: `data_out[0]` and `data_out[1]` are both references to the same underlying object.  Create a new `dict` (and don't touch the old one) if you want two distinct containers that don't share a common fate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_out` is `[this_data_out]` after the first `.append()` call, and then it's `[this_data_out, this_data_out]` after the second one.

Appending it to a list didn't copy its contents, it just put a pointer to what was in `this_data_out` in there - so when you changed that dictionary, what you saw in the list changed as well.

Comment: Thanks, I got this from above comment. What should we do to avoid this?

Comment: @PappuJha: you can `.append(this_data_out.copy())` but note that then the keys and values are *not* copied. Since these also are references.

Comment: Thanks, this helps.